# SELECT 1 - какой смысл этого запроса?

Tags: select, sql

Какой смысл несет SQL запрос `SELECT 1`.

Знаю, что он возвращает единицу, но зачем это нужно?

Где его применяют на практике?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну например, что бы проверить, работает ли база вообще. Потому что если она этот запрос не может обработать, то дела плохи.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще говоря, это вычисляемый столбец: select <выражение>,...
А так в зависимости от контекста. 
Например, с предикатом [NOT] EXISTS, т.к. выводить что-нибудь в списке столбцов смысла не имеет.

Answer (score 3):

С помощью подобных запросов, можно почти бесплатно генерировать числовые последовательности...

Сам по себе - просто получить константу)

```
select
  n2.n * 4 + n1.n + 1 as n
from
  ( select n = 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 ) n1,
  ( select n = 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 ) n2
```